# Get users friends list in Graph API version 2.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-friends

I am developing an application in which the user will be logged in using Facebook credentials.

Once the user is logged in I need to retrieve the user's friends list. But as per new [Facebook Graph API version 2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends),I cant get the list of friends until the user's friends logs in to the application.

Is there any possibility to take the user's friends list without user's friends logging in to the application.

If the user cant get the friends list, how come he can invite his friends to the application and asks his permission to retrieve his details? Is there any other way to do this?

Is it possible to fetch the entire friends list of a user by using FQL. If so will it affect the app in the future?

I am new to facebook apps.Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a canvas game you can use invitable_friends ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.0 ). Otherwise you can use the Share or Send/Message dialogs.

Comment: Is it possible to fetch the entire friends list of a user by using FQL. If so will it affect the app in the future?

Comment: If you are using API v2.0 you can not get all friends